# Add Sheet reference to Excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to add sheet references to a range of existing formulas that don't have any sheet references?

Simple Example:

**Range A1:A2 of Sheet1**

A1: `=A1` → `=Sheet1!A1`

A2: `=ROUNDUP(B2,0)` → `=ROUNDUP(Sheet1!B2,0)`

Failed Attempts:

- **Find & Replace** has no constant symbol to grab (not always by "=", not always the same column letter, etc.)
- **Copy to different worksheet** - some complain that the reference changes when doing this. I could use this as a solution but my formula stays same - relative to the sheet it's in.

I'd prefer to avoid macros.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free [regular expression add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) for Excel.

Besides worksheet functions it also has a regular expression enabled find-replace form. With that you can add sheet name:

- Find what: `\b[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,4}\b`

  - where `\b` is word boundary, `[A-Z]{1,3}` and `[0-9]{1,4}` is looking for letters and numbers respectively
- Replace with: `<sheetname>!$1`

  - put your sheet's name instead of `<sheetname>`

I know it's not completely a macro free solution, but I don't know any good solution without macros, and with this you don't need any VBA knowledge.

Comment: alright. thank you. 
it seems most of my issues now hinge on learning VBA.